# Bootstrap code not working: Row & Col, Checkboxes displaying vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to align 32 checkboxes w/labels in rows that are 4 across. It is currently stacking all 32 vertically. I've modeled my code after other examples but am still getting the same results no matter what I seem to do. Not sure if it's my html or css...

Here is a JS Bin link:  https://jsbin.com/pepejom/edit?html,css,output

Here is my html:

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <link id="ppstyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

      </head>

      <body onLoad="onLoaded()">
        <div class="container">
                <section class="panel" id="data">
                    <div id="dataSelection">

                        <div class="container" id="allTeams">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12"><input class="radio_checkbox" id="allTeams" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">All Teams</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container" id="singleTeams1">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3800" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">ARI</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">ATL</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0325" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">BAL</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0610" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">BUF</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container" id="singleTeams2">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0750" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CAR</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0810" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CHI</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0920" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CIN</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1050" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CLE</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">DAL</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1400" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">DEN</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1540" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">DET</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1800" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">GB</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2120" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">HOU</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">IND</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2250" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">JAX</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2310" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">KC</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2510" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">LA</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4400" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">LAC</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2700" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">MIA</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3000" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">MIN</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NE</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3300" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NO</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3410" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NYG</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3430" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NYJ</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2520" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">OAK</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3700" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">PHI</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3900" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">PIT</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4600" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">SEA</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4500" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">SF</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4900" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">TB</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2100" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">TEN</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="5110" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">WAS</div>
                          </div><!-- end single teams row -->
                        </div><!-- end single teams container -->
                    </div><!-- end dataSelection -->
                </section><!-- end panel: data -->   

        </div><!-- end container -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my css:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight:200;
    letter-spacing: .07em;
    color:#757575;
    background-color:#262626;
}

.panel {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 260px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #333333;  1F1F1F
  background-color:#292929;
}

.radio_checkbox { margin-right: 5px; }

div {
    /* text-align: left; */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.centered {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The html above uses links from JS Bin for bootstrap. In my actual code I link to bootstrap that I have downloaded and use locally...

```
<script src="./lib/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/ext.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link id="ppstyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the width attribute from the **.panel** to **.container { width: 260px; }** and it should work.

---

Also I did some changes on your code so it is to closer the bootstrap standards. Hope it helps...!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: 200;
            letter-spacing: .07em;
            color: #757575;
            background-color:#262626;
        }

        .container {
            width: 260px;
        }

        .panel {
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 0 auto 5px;
            border: 1px solid #333333;
            background-color:#292929;
        }

        .block-checkboxes {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .block-checkboxes > div,
        .centered > div,
        #allTeams {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .block-checkboxes input {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .centered label {
            border: solid 1px #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section class="panel" id="data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="allTeams">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="all-teams">All Teams</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- If you want radio buttons set type="radio" and give them the same name -->
        <div class="row centered" id="singleTeams1">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3800" type="radio" name="single-teams1">ARI</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="0200" type="radio" name="single-teams1">ATL</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="0325" type="radio" name="single-teams1">BAL</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="0610" type="radio" name="single-teams1">BUF</label></div>
        </div>

        <!-- or if you want checkboxes so that you can get multiple items give them a name as an array -->
        <div class="row block-checkboxes" id="singleTeams2">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="0750" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">CAR</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="0810" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">CHI</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="0920" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">CIN</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="1050" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">CLE</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="1200" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">DAL</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="1400" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">DEN</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="1540" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">DET</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="1800" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">GB</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2120" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">HOU</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2200" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">IND</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2250" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">JAX</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2310" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">KC</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2510" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">LA</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="4400" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">LAC</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2700" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">MIA</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3000" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">MIN</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3200" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">NE</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3300" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">NO</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3410" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">NYG</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3430" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">NYJ</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2520" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">OAK</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3700" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">PHI</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="3900" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">PIT</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="4600" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">SEA</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="4500" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">SF</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="4900" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">TB</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="2100" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">TEN</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><label><input value="5110" type="checkbox" name="teams[]">WAS</label></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*I embedded the style to the same document to be more compact, you can always separate it*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I can't seem to move the labels away from the checkboxes. I've tried adding padding and/or margins on multiple css styles with no luck.

Comment: You can add margin-bottom on the inputs, for example go to **.block-checkboxes input** and set **margin: 0 auto 10px;**  excuse me if I misunderstood..

Answer (score 1):

Try using `table-cell` property for div containers, `.container` class.

just add this:

```
.container{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Something like this:

```css
.container{
    display: table-cell;
}

* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight:200;
    letter-spacing: .07em;
    color:#757575;
    background-color:#262626;
}

.panel {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 260px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #333333;  1F1F1F
  background-color:#292929;
}

.radio_checkbox { margin-right: 10px !important; }

div {
    /* text-align: left; */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.centered {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
      <link id="ppstyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body onLoad="onLoaded()">
      <div class="container">
         <section class="panel" id="data">
            <div id="dataSelection">
               <div class="container" id="allTeams">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12"><input class="radio_checkbox" id="allTeams" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">All Teams</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="container" id="singleTeams1">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3800" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">ARI</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">ATL</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0325" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">BAL</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 centered"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0610" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">BUF</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="container" id="singleTeams2">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0750" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CAR</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0810" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CHI</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0920" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CIN</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1050" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CLE</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">DAL</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1400" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">DEN</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1540" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">DET</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1800" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">GB</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2120" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">HOU</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">IND</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2250" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">JAX</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2310" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">KC</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2510" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">LA</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4400" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">LAC</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2700" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">MIA</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3000" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">MIN</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3200" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NE</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3300" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NO</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3410" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NYG</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3430" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">NYJ</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2520" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">OAK</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3700" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">PHI</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="3900" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">PIT</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4600" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">SEA</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4500" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">SF</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="4900" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">TB</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="2100" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">TEN</div>
                     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="5110" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">WAS</div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- end single teams row -->
               </div>
               <!-- end single teams container -->
            </div>
            <!-- end dataSelection -->
         </section>
         <!-- end panel: data -->   
      </div>
      <!-- end container -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working - with some strange results... The labels are sometimes to the right of the checkbox and sometimes below. I also had to move the divs into groups of 4.  I'm also noticing that it's stacking them top to bottom instead of left to right.

Comment: Great - `The labels are sometimes to the right of the checkbox and sometimes below.` try adjust them by changing padding, margins.

Comment: I'm able to get the labels to the right of the checkbox using .col-md-3 { padding: 2px; } but can't move the labels away from the checkbox. Do I need to create a class for the labels and add padding/margins to that?

Comment: you can move the labels away from the checkbox just by changing `.radio_checkbox`  `margin-right` with **!important**, like this `.radio_checkbox { margin-right: 10px !important; }`

Comment: I've tried .radio_checkbox { margin-right: 10px; } and .radio_checkbox { margin-right: 10px !important; } and nothing is working.

Comment: it's strange, it's work for me. I've updated the code snippet and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the groups of four in rows:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0750" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CAR</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0810" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CHI</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0920" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CIN</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1050" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CLE</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0750" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CAR</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0810" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CHI</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="0920" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CIN</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><input class="radio_checkbox" value="1050" type="checkbox" name="allTeams">CLE</div>
</div>
etc....
```

Comment: I tried that in my example above. The first group contains 4 and the second group contains many. The group of 4 didn't display any differently.

Comment: Something is wrong with your links to bootstrap.  If you inspect the output none of the bootstrap styles are applied

Comment: The above example is actually using the links from JS Bin for bootstrap. In my actual code I have downloaded bootstrap locally and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I removed the css that I have and used a bootstrap cdn and it does what I'm looking for but it spreads the columns all across the page. How do I keep them confined to a specific width?

Comment: I would put the whole thing inside another container with the width that you want, or just set the width of the `container` element